# Parameters in a postgres utility script

Tags: database, postgresql, shell

I need to create an utility script to add an item in a postgres database.
My initial approach is to have a bash script with a minimum set of non default values and a postgres sql script with the remaining default columns. Item table has 20 columns.

So here is my simplified bash script:

```
## A unique system identifier for an Item.
ID_ITM='318'
## The description of the Item.
DE_ITM="A description"

psql -U postgres -d MYDB -v id_itm=$ID_ITM de_itm=$DE_ITM -f insertItemPostgres.sql
```

As you can see it calls the following sql script(simplified):

```
Insert into AS_ITM (ID_ITM,ID_LN_PRC,ID_ITM_SL_PRC,ID_MRHRC_GP,ID_RU_ITM_SL,ID_DPT_PS,FL_ITM_DSC,FL_ADT_ITM_PRC,NM_BRN,FL_AZN_FR_SLS,LU_ITM_USG,NM_ITM,DE_ITM,TY_ITM,LU_KT_ST,DE_ITM_LNG,FL_ITM_SBST_IDN,LU_CLN_ORD,LU_EXM_TX,FL_VLD_SRZ_ITM)
values (:id_itm,:de_itm,null,'64',null,null,null,null,null,'1',null,null,null,null,'0',null,'0',null,'0','0');
```

My problem is that to make this work I need to have the string and ids with two pairs of quotes:

```
DE_ITM="'A description'"
```

I need to find out how can I pass the parameters in a literal.

I will appreciate any better way to do it, because I know this is not the best and my db scripting skills are not the best. Also I'm using a bash script but I could be just a sql with the non default values that calls the one that has the insert.

Comment: Do you have to use a shell script for this? Dealing with all the quoting and escaping issues will be a lot easier in almost any other scripting language.

Comment: No, I'm doing some research now, I would like to do it just in sql. but I don't want to modify the database creating a function. I want just a script with the values of the variables, so QA can add the items in a easy way.

Comment: i would very strongly suggest you just write this in Python or Perl and use DBI or DBAPI as appropriate

Comment: You don't need to bring in a bunch of ORM nonsense, just a very thing DBI-ish wrapper so that you can prepare a statement with placeholders, bind values to those placeholders, and then execute the statement. Trying to handling quoting in the shell is madness and will take years off your life.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [psql 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html#AEN75612) or later, you can try the following:

First you'll need to quote the expansion of your two variables in the shell, like so:

```
psql -U postgres -d MYDB -v "id_itm=${ID_ITM}" -v "de_itm=${DE_ITM}" -f insertItemPostgres.sql
```

Then in your SQL you'll need to reference the variables using the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO as_itm (id_itm, id_ln_prc, ...)
VALUES (:'id_itm', :'de_itm', ...)
```

---

Alas, this didn't work for you for some reason.  So here's a more old-school approach which should work on all psql versions:  Use special bash syntax to double the quotes in your variables.

```
psql -U postgres -d MYDB -f insertItemPostgres.sql \
    -v "id_itm='${ID_ITM//\'/''}'" \
    -v "de_itm='${DE_ITM//\'/''}'"
```

In this case the variable references in your SQL should look unchanged from the OP: `VALUES (:id_itm, :de_itm, ...`

Comment: This doesn't work and I have psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.1

Comment: Oh well.  I've expanded my answer to include the other approach I might try.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell HERE-document: shell variables are expanded, even in single quotes.

```
#!/bin/sh

## A unique system identifier for an Item.
ID_ITM="318"
## The description of the Item.
DE_ITM="A description"

psql -U postgres -d MYDB << THE_END
Insert into AS_ITM(ID_ITM, ID_LN_PRC, ID_ITM_SL_PRC, ID_MRHRC_GP, ID_RU_ITM_SL
   , ID_DPT_PS, FL_ITM_DSC, FL_ADT_ITM_PRC, NM_BRN, FL_AZN_FR_SLS
   , LU_ITM_USG, NM_ITM,DE_ITM, TY_ITM, LU_KT_ST, DE_ITM_LNG
   , FL_ITM_SBST_IDN, LU_CLN_ORD, LU_EXM_TX, FL_VLD_SRZ_ITM)
values ('$ID_TTM', null,'64', null, null
       , null, null, '$DE_ITM' , '1', null
       , null, null, null, '0', null
        , '0', null, '0', '0');

THE_END
```